# AWS Aurora Postgresql oracle_fdw tls server connection

Tags: ssl, oracle-fdw

Using extension oracle_fdw within AWS RDS Aurora-Postgresql v12.12
oracle_fdw:

```
oracle_diag                                                 |
------------------------------------------------------------+
oracle_fdw 2.3.0, PostgreSQL 12.12, Oracle client 21.7.0.0.0|
```

When I create a server connection 'Create Server' to an Oracle database, does it use tls >= 1.2 by default? If not is there a way to enable tls on this server connection?

Cannot find any reference for tls with oracle_fdw. Need to make this connection secure in transit.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the advice in [this oracle_fdw issue](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw/issues/622#issuecomment-1794811414):

> I really suggest to follow oracle-base tutorial : https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/native-network-encryption-for-database-connections
> Tim Hall is also an OCM and he knows his stuff. His documentation is more concise and clearer than Oracle official docs.
>
> Key parts:
>
> > "From 10g Release 2 onward, Native Network Encryption and [TCP/IP with SSL/TLS](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/configure-tcpip-with-ssl-and-tls-for-database-connections) are no longer part of the [Advanced Security Option](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/license.102/b14199/options.htm#DBLIC138). Native network encryption gives you the ability to encrypt database connections, without the configuration overhead of TCP/IP and SSL/TLS and without the need to open and listen on different ports."
>
> Oracle 11g or later users can utilize this feature without an expensive option.
>
> > "If we require AES256 encryption on all connections to the server, we would add the following to the server side "sqlnet.ora" file. The client does not need to be altered as the default settings (ACCEPTED and no named encryption algorithm) will allow it to successfully negotiate a connection.
> >
> > ```
> > SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER=REQUIRED
> > SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER=(AES256)
> > ```
>
> Just one file to edit server side and that's all.

Comment: So setting ssl from the client is not possible when connecting via fdw to Oracle? They would have to set server side NNE.

Comment: ... also to use NNE the client needs to support it also: "Clients that do not support native network encryption can fall back to unencrypted connections while incompatibility is mitigated." [NNE Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-network-data-encryption-and-integrity.html#GUID-8F489523-9693-4147-ADFD-C05246C98790)

Comment: The PostgreSQL server is the Oracle client. The encryption between PostgreSQL client and server is completely unrelated. Use an Oracle client version that supports Oracle Native Network Encryption (although if you tie yourself down in the Amazon cloud, you cannot control that).

Comment: Is it possible to validate ssl connection from Postgresql side using: SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'network_protocol') FROM DUAL; this should return tcps if tls being used on the connection?

Comment: Sure. Define a foreign table using that query.

Comment: Since based on your documentation the 'table' option is required. How do you reference an Oracle function instead?    create foreign table syscontext (
    context varchar2(100)
     ) SERVER edr OPTIONS (schema 'SYS', table '?')

Comment: You don't specify `schema` and set `table '(SELECT SYS_CONTEXT(''USERENV'', ''network_protocol'') FROM dual)'`.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe that worked! Not the results I needed since it returns 'tcp' not 'tcps' from the aurora postgresql cluster but it does work.

Comment: can we set the protocol to 'TCPS' instead of how it's connecting 'TCP' under the dbserver variable? CREATE SERVER edr_fdw FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER oracle_fdw
              OPTIONS (**dbserver** '//server:port/ndc', isolation_level 'read_committed');

Comment: You can use anything you can use to connect with sqlplus. I personally have no experience with encrypted connections in Oracle.